# Spring Boot Sockjs vs Socket.io

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, socket.io, stomp, sockjs

I'm trying to build a scalable, secure, robust websocket application that will deliver chat messages, market rates, trades, real time updates/notifications, timer/countdowns

I found this example: https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-websocket-chat-example/
I realize the potential, since I already know Spring Boot and I can use this as my Websocket server.

Tech Stack: Spring, STOMP, SockJS, RabbitMQ

However I noticed it uses SockJS. Then I searched for alternatives and seems a popular choice is Socket.io. Their website says it all and possible solutions. But it's NodeJS.

Tech Stack: NodeJS, Socket.io

Answer (score 1):

If you already know Spring Boot you can go with the [Java implementation](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio) of socket.io.

Comment: Thank you! I’m checking their demos, I just hope they have a large community I could ask in any case I bump into issues